# How to handle selected items in a growing sap.m.List

Tags: typescript, sapui5

I have a rather large sap.m.List with up to 10.000 list entries.
For performance reasons, I enabled the growing feature of the list:

```
const list = new List({
      growing: true,
      growingThreshold: 50,
      growingScrollToLoad: true,
      itemPress: (oEvent) => void this.onListItemPressed(oEvent),
      mode: ListMode.SingleSelectMaster,
      width: '100%',
      items: {
        path: this._path,
        factory: this.createItem.bind(this),
      });
```

When opening the view with this list, I want to set the selected list item. However, if the item to select isn't in the first 50 list items, the selection isn't shown (probably becaus the item isn't rendered yet). How can i fix this?

I tried to directly load and render all list items, however the performance in this case is miserable. Also, I don't want to change the order of the list items (that the item to select is in the first 50 elements).

Comment: sap recommends to only use `sap.m.table` for up to 200 rows, or whatever you'd consider moderate: https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/table-overview/

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the use case? Also, which model is `this._path` referring to?